# Running r models on AWS - do multiple vCPUs function like a multicore system?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, parallel-processing

I'm running models in the r package 'secr'. The simplest models take days to complete on a 4G macbook and I've already done everything possible within the model's setup to decrease run time. Parallel (multicore) processing is possible and straightforward in secr, but benefits are minimal and run time may actually increase. Am I likely to see improvement in run time if I switch to a high-powered virtual machine in the cloud (e.g. AWS's EC2 with 16 RAM and 4 vCPUs), or do the EC2's four vCPUs function like a multicore system (in which case I would only benefit from one vCPU despite having 4)?

I've asked this question in a couple of different forums and received conflicting answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of the vCPUs just like a multicore system. They would appear as multiple cores to any software running on the system.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. It depends. You may see a improvement in runtime if you switch to a EC2 instance type with better virtual hardware specifications. AWS runs a custom version of the Xen hypervisor, and your getting vCPUs as you pointed out.  Performance will depend on the variability of the other guests's workloads. If the vCPUs are all assigned to instances, and each instance is running CPU heavy workloads, your going to see a downward trend in performance. It depends on the pattern of usage of all the instances running on the hypervisor. This article from Citrix explains some of the nuances of balancing vCPU time between instances on Xen and why performance will vary:

[Citrix on Xen vCPU Performance](https://www.citrix.com/blogs/2014/03/11/citrix-xenserver-setting-more-than-one-vcpu-per-vm-to-improve-application-performance-and-server-consolidation-e-g-for-cad3-d-graphical-applications/%20[Citrix%20on%20Xen%20vCPU%20performance])

The instance type matters, not only the vCPUs and RAM. Avoid the T2 instances because they are 'burstable' and CPU performance will certainly vary. This article from AWS recommends to try M4 instance types for parallelization with R:

[Running R on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/running-r-on-aws/)

For specific types of EC2 instances you can control the C-state (sleep levels a core can enter when it is idle) and P-State (desired performance in frequency from a core). This would allow you to tune your instance performance for your workload. The following link explains in detail what instance types allow for C-State and P-State control and shows you how to use the utility "stress" to benchmark and tune different configurations.

[EC2: Processor State Control](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/processor_state_control.html)

It would be best to design a test when you first provision the instance to see if it the type meets your performance requirements and then run the test again later to see if the performance benchmark holds.

Comment: *"Avoid the T2 instances because they are 'burstable' and CPU performance will certainly vary."*  Not exactly.  `t2` machines have 100% of the core(s) available as long as you have not exhausted your CPU credits (visible in CloudWatch). Burstable doesn't mean variable or unpredictable in the sense you're implying.  It's not a "best effort" or shared core platform.  Burstable means you can't run the cores at 100% 24/7, because you will deplete your credits faster than you can earn them -- only then is the speed throttled.  The `t1`, in contrast, was extremely variable, and terrible.

Comment: Good clarification on the T2 instance type.